# Entity Framework 6 - ASP.NET Filter - Concurrent Adds

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have Web Api 2 set up with Entity Framework.

I have made an `ActionFilterAttribute` which SHOULD log every call into the database.

This works fine if calls are made one at a time. But if multiple calls are made at the same time it fails. Being confused about the different types of concurrency, I will ask the question for my specific scenario.

How can I modify my existing code so that database entries can be added without conflict for concurrent calls?

As a side note: Each log entry does have an ID which should be database generated.

```
public class AppLogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //private AppContext db = new AppContext(); //I can use this or the using statement.

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        var ip = ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name);
        var url = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
        var date = DateTime.Now;

        var logEntry = new LogEntry
        {
            Date = date,
            IpAddress = ip,
            Url = url,
            UserID = userId
        };

        //Problems here for concurrent calls!
        using (var db = new AppContext())
        {
            db.LogEntries.Add(logEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The LogEntry Class ...

```
public class LogEntry
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters in ASP.NET are created once and cached, and that's why you cannot inject your dependencies through the filter's constructor because they will be resolved/injected once, so in your case if you declared the context as a private variable it will be a singleton object, and that's why you have your problems with concurrency because you are using the same context with the same 2 requests to add at the same time.

One option to solve your problem would be using the [GetDependencyScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getdependencyscope%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method through the actionContext parameter, so your code can be something like this:

```
public class AppLogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        var ip = ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name);
        var url = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
        var date = DateTime.Now;

        var logEntry = new LogEntry
        {
            Date = date,
            IpAddress = ip,
            Url = url,
            UserID = userId
        };

        // get the AppContext from the current scope 
        var appContext = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(AppContext)) as AppContext;

        if (appContext != null)
        {
            appContext.LogEntries.Add(logEntry);
            appContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above solution assumes that you already set the Ioc container as the dependency Resolver in your Api config section, so something like this if you were using Autofac Ioc:

```
    _container = builder.Build();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(_container);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any ideas without an IOC?

Comment: Thanks, moving 'AppContext db = new AppContext();' inside the method fixed it. The caching of the filters was the problem.

Comment: That's because you will create a new instance every time you execute the filter, if you work against interfaces, then you will need the GetDependencyScope way.